# Flexible sidebar database design

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my system I have a flexible layout, where you can place your sidebar left or right (or both). You can add multiple sidebars and then choose which one you want to use for your page, and on which location.

**What is the best way to store the items in a sidebar, while maintaining the ability to edit the item configuration per sidebar?**

The items consist of a php class in which the config options are passed through to a template file.

My origional thought was to implement some sort of shortcode functionality and add a shortcode to a sidebar_item entry in the database, but this way it wouldn't really be configurable.

Comment: I don't actually see the problem. What is "sidebar"? Is it something that groups items? Are the items retrieved from the db?

Comment: The sidebar is an object which groups items together to form a "sidebar" in the frontend. The items can be everything from just a block of text to a navigation list.

Comment: Does sidebar have its own configuration or it "inherits" it from configurations from items? Are they retrieved from the db?

Comment: Sidebar doesn't have a configuration, it is just a container for it's items. The item's arent stored in the database yet, that is what I want to acheive. The items are a combination of a PHP file and a Template (html/php) file. I want a way to assign the items to a sidebar in the database, while maintaining the ability to configure some (predifined) options

Comment: Maybe add a table "sidebars" and let each item have its reference to the sidebar it is in?

Comment: Yes, but a Item can be in multiple sidebar and the items do not have a database entry yet.

Comment: _“but a Item can be in multiple sidebar”_ – then create multiple records, one for each item:sidebar pair. _“the items do not have a database entry yet”_ – you can’t reference something that does not already exist.

Comment: @CBroe, yes maybe I phrased it a bit wrong. I'm looking for a way to store the items in the database, by class reference or something, together with the configuration of that item, so the sidebar can reference to it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have:

- a user, who can place a sidebar where he wants to,
- a sidebar, that can contain some elements,
- items, that can belong to each sidebar to each user,
- files to handle items of different types.

and every user has his own sidebar with his own content.

I can propose tables:

- `users` in which users are defined by some id,
- `sidebars` in which you say which user it belongs to, and if it is left or right,
- `item_types` where you say which template and/or configuration files should be used,
- `items` in what type it is (from `item_types`), so you know which template to use, then in which sidebar (from `sidebars`) it is, maybe what position it is (first, second, ...).

You should create relations between:

- `sidebars` and `users` on user id so selecting user you could know which sidebar(s) he owns,
- `items` and `sidebars` on sidebar id, so knowing sidebar you know which items are in it,
- `item_types` and `items` on item type so you know how to handle it,

Perhaps, in `items` you can also store configuration variables that you could pass to template.